# How to use jq to format array of objects to separated list of key values

Tags: jq

How can I (generically) transform the input file below to the output file below, using jq.  The record format of the output file is: array_index | key | value

**Input file:**

```
[{"a": 1, "b": 10},
 {"a": 2, "d": "fred", "e": 30}]
```

**Output File:**

```
0|a|1
0|b|10
1|a|2
1|d|fred
1|e|30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `tostream`, which creates a stream of paths and their values. Filter out those having values using `select`, `flatten` to align both, and `join` for the output format:

```sh
jq -r 'tostream | select(has(1)) | flatten | join("|")'
```

```json
0|a|1
0|b|10
1|a|2
1|d|fred
1|e|30
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/VQqmJ11D83)

Or a very similar one using `paths` to get the paths, `scalars` for the filter, and `getpath` for the corresponding value:

```sh
jq -r 'paths(scalars) as $p | [$p[], getpath($p)] | join("|")'
```

```json
0|a|1
0|b|10
1|a|2
1|d|fred
1|e|30
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ExGOQiaf7v)

Answer (score 0):

```
< file.json jq -r 'to_entries
                   | .[] 
                   | .key as $k
                   | ((.value | to_entries )[]
                      | [$k, .key, .value])
                   | @csv'
```

Output:

```
0,"a",1
0,"b",10
1,"a",2
1,"d","fred"
1,"e",30
```

You just need to remove the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

`to_entries` can be used to loop over the elements of arrays and objects in a way that gives both the key (index) and the value of the element.

```sh
jq -r '
   to_entries[] |
   .key as $id |
   .value |
   to_entries[] |
   [ $id, .key, .value ] |
   join("|")
'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/hWKu2TbJ3z) on jqplay

Replace `join("|")` with `@csv` to get proper CSV.