# How to use jq to transform array of objects into separated list of key values - Outputing specific key value instead of array index

Tags: json, key, jq

This is related to my previous question:
[How to use jq to format array of objects to separated list of key values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71825711/how-to-use-jq-to-format-array-of-objects-to-separated-list-of-key-values)

How can I (generically) transform the input file below to the output file below, using jq. The value at key "id" uniqely identifies the array element. The record format of the output file is: (value at key "id") | key | value.

I can do this if I add awk to solution of previous question, but I am having trouble getting my head around doing it all in jq.

**Input file:**

```
[{"id": 11, "b": 100},
 {"id": 12, "d": "fred", "e": 300}]
```

**Output File:**

```
11|id|11
11|b|100
12|id|12
12|d|fred
12|e|300
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using `to_entries`, which decomposes an object into an array of key-value pairs:

```sh
jq -r '.[] | .id as $id | to_entries[] | [$id,.key,.value] | join("|")'
```

```json
11|id|11
11|b|100
12|id|12
12|d|fred
12|e|300
```

Comment: This is the exact same thing that I came up with.

Comment: This is a nice solution that has helped me learn jq